# Memory Address and values in memory address

Tags: c, pointers, null, structure

I have a little confusion.

```
struct node *p; and if(p==NULL)
```

Now what I have gathered based upon my studies is that NULL is not a memory address but a value (i.e 0) in the memory address. When I use `if(*p==NULL)` it gives an error - no match for 'operator=='. But doesn't `*p` gives the value in the memory address. If we just use `p` aren't we comparing a memory address with a value in the memory address. Why is `p==NULL` correct while `*p=NULL` is not.

Comment: the notion of NULL is a predefined area of memory which is unreferencable. it is ( ideally ) where you initialise pointers to before you allocate them properly. the traditional null check is applied to the pointer itself not dereferencing it ( which is UB and could cause a segfault )

Comment: `NULL` is used with pointers. Here `if(p==NULL)` , `p` is a pointer and can be compared with `NULL` (assuming `p` is a global variable so that it is auto-initialized to `NULL`). But here `if(*p==NULL)` , `*p` is of type `struct node` and that is not a pointer.

Comment: You really need better study materials, if you gathered that.

Comment: @M.M I was really looking for an answer but I will act upon your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *If we just use `p` aren't we comparing a memory address with a value in the memory address*

No. When we talk about `NULL`, as per the `C11` standard, chapter §7.19, `<stddef.h>`, (emphasis mine)

> `NULL`
>   which expands to an implementation-defined **null pointer constant**;[...]

So, `NULL` is a pointer and in your code, so is `p`. So, you can compare them.

OTOH, `*p` is a value, and you cannot compare that with `NULL`.

Comment: My idea of null wasn't proper. Got it finally.

Comment: @Rishab Note: null and NULL are **not** the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `*p` gives the value in a memory address. But in this case, that value is a `struct node` because `p` is of type "pointer to struct node". You can't compare a structure's value to NULL.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding about NULL here. NULL does in fact function as an address — it is a value for which a pointer is not valid. The memory at address NULL cannot be retrieved. NULL is NOT a value stored in a pointer. NULL is a pointer, and though it is system dependent, it usually points to the memory address 0, which I think is the source of the confusion.

NULL is comparable to pointers ( often defined as (void *)0 ). the conversion from void * to struct node will give a compiler warning and doesnt make sense.

Additionally comparing *p to NULL involves first dereferencing p ( which is UB )

NULL may have the value of 0, but it isn't meant to be compared to anything that isn't a pointer. So to fix your problem, as the commenters said, you must change your comparison from

```
if (*p == NULL)
```

a comparison of a struct to a memory address, to

```
if (p == NULL)
```

which compares memory address p to the address value stored in NULL.

Comment: this sentence : `If NULL was equal to zero, and was stored at a certain memory address, then any time you had a pointer to some variable with a value of zero it would be equal to NULL and that just doesn't make sense`

Comment: I was trying to fix the confusion in the original post. Rishab said his understanding was that NULL was a value, i.e. 0, and that by dereferencing a pointer and comparing it to NULL he could tell if something existed or not. My attempt was to make it clear that, for example if you had int *i = 0, in his view comparing the dereferencing of that pointer to NULL would tell him if it was a valid pointer. If his view was correct, it would be impossible to tell if a pointer was NULL if it pointed to any value equal to zero. I'm sorry if the original sentence was worded confusingly.

Comment: Damn, my bad. I actually read [link]http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/NULL/ thats why I said NULL is zero.

Comment: @forsooth it does make sense for pointers to store NULL ( usually defined as zero ). and the usual object checking code will use something like `pointer = malloc(20*sizeof(char)); if(!pointer)...`. so in practical usage we do have pointers with a value of zero which we are comparing to NULL as standard practice. the c standard does not define NULL as zero but in most implementations it is

Comment: I know, I understand why you voted down, no worries. I was more trying to correct the misunderstanding that NULL should be compared to the dereferencing of anything that's not a pointer to a pointer. I meant "NULL is not equal to zero" in the sense of NULL not being a mystical value of 0 that can compare to the contents of any pointer, but  rather a pointer to the address 0 (usually) in memory.

Comment: Deal, I hope that's clear enough. It's a tricky concept to explain. Thanks for the discussion anyway, if anything it probably elucidated the use of NULL a little more.